# How to use .loc when the value of dataframe elements are list [python pandas]

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe `df` where the elements in `df.trajec` is a list.

For example, `df.ix['smith']['trajec'] = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b']`

`type(df.ix['smith']) = list`

In this case, I found out that I cannot use such command.

```
aaa = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b']
df.loc[df.trajec == aaa]
```

And it gives me an error message like below.

`ValueError: Arrays were different lengths: 8886 vs 5`

Is there any way to find the subset of the dataframe `df` where `df.trajec` is equal to a list `aaa`?

Comment: Please show a self-contained example with sample data demonstrating the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html) for creating `mask`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'trajec':[['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b'],
                             ['a', 'b'],
                             ['a','c', 'b']]}, 
                   index=['smith','smith1','smith2'])

print (df)
                 trajec
smith   [a, b, c, a, b]
smith1           [a, b]
smith2        [a, c, b]

aaa = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b']
mask = df.trajec.apply(lambda x: x == aaa)
print (mask)
smith      True
smith1    False
smith2    False
Name: trajec, dtype: bool

#loc can be omit if need filter all columns
print (df[mask])
                trajec
smith  [a, b, c, a, b]

#if need apply mask and return only column `trajec`
print (df.loc[mask, 'trajec'])
smith    [a, b, c, a, b]
Name: trajec, dtype: object
```

Another possible `mask` is by `list comprehension`:

```
mask = [x == aaa for x in df.trajec.values]
print (mask)
[True, False, False]

print (df[mask])
                trajec
smith  [a, b, c, a, b]
```

Comment: Thank you @jezrael. This is exactly what I want. I often use `apply` function, on the other hands, I often forgot when I need `apply`.

Comment: Yes, if use `list` in `pandas`, it is more complicated. Thank you for acepting! Nice day!

Answer (score 0):

```
print df[df.trajec.apply(tuple) == ('a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b')]    
                trajec
smith  [a, b, c, a, b]
```

And this solution seems to be 20% faster than the accepted one:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(100000, 1)), columns=['trajec'])
df = df.assign(trajec=df.trajec.apply(lambda x: [x]))

%timeit df[df.trajec.apply(tuple) == (42,)]
10 loops, best of 3: 23.3 ms per loop

%timeit df[df.trajec.apply(lambda x: x == [42])]
10 loops, best of 3: 29 ms per loop
```

Interestingly, the list comprehension solution from the accepted answer is even faster:

```
%timeit df[[x == [42] for x in df.trajec.values]]
10 loops, best of 3: 21.7 ms per loop
```